# Reading pusher data

Tags: javascript, arrays, callback, pusher

Can someone help me with the reading of the returned pusher message in the example callback.  I've taken this example straight from their website, but the alert box just says 'undefined', however the console.log outputs everything fine.  I'm sending test messages via their API console in the account control panel.  I'm changing the key and channel accordingly, the code below is for the benefit of stackoverflow.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <title>Pusher Test</title>
  <script src="//js.pusher.com/2.2/pusher.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    // Enable pusher logging - don't include this in production
    Pusher.log = function(message) {
      if (window.console && window.console.log) {
        window.console.log(message);
      }
    };

    var pusher = new Pusher('MYAPIKEY');
    var channel = pusher.subscribe('test_channel');
    channel.bind('my_event', function(data) {
      alert(data.message);
    });
  </script>
</head>
```

I've tried `data[0].message` and `data.data` and it always returns undefined. If I alert `data` then it returns `[object] [object]` as expected, so there is something there I just can't display it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The structure of the `data` variable depends on the event data you are sending through Pusher. You can use the Pusher Debug Console to test this out. The example in the image below will work and show `hello` in an alert for the code you have in your question.

[image]

Comment: Perfect, thank you!! I was sending in JSON format but didn't have a key called 'message' - that'll do it!!